# Using fgetc with stdin pointer. Error handling input

Tags: c

I just want to ask why on my function `read_int` does not accept my input from `fgetc` as `int`? (I figured that is the case because I always input an integer yet it still go to my `int` function that displays error.

Here's my code (with skel code from my prof):

```
int main() {
    int the_int;
    double the_double;
    printf("Doing tests of read_int and read_double functions ...\n\n");
    printf("Please try to enter an int: ");
    the_int = read_int();
    printf("read_int succeeded.  It read a value of %d.\n", the_int);
    printf("Please try to enter a double: ");
    the_double = read_double();
    printf("read_double succeeded.  It read a value of %g.\n", the_double);
    return 0;
}

int read_int(void) {
    int f = fgetc(stdin);
    if (fgetc(stdin) != EOF) {
        printf("Sorry that is invalid.");
        exit(1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Comment: The `c` in [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) is for ***c**haracter*. It reads characters from the file.

Answer (score 2):

`fgetc()` is for reading bytes from the stream, it returns one character at a time.

To read an `int`, use `scanf("%d", &f)` and to read a `double`, `scanf("%lf", &d)` with `f` and `d` defined as `int f;` and `double d;` respectively.

Also include `<stdio.h>` and define the functions before calling them.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int read_int(void) {
    int f;
    if (scanf("%d", &f) != 1) {
        printf("Sorry that input is invalid.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return f;
}

double read_double(void) {
    double d;
    if (scanf("%lf", &d) != 1) {
        printf("Sorry that input is invalid.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return d;
}

int main(void) {
    int the_int;
    double the_double;

    printf("Doing tests of read_int and read_double functions ...\n\n");
    printf("Please try to enter an int: ");
    the_int = read_int();
    printf("read_int succeeded.  It read a value of %d.\n", the_int);
    printf("Please try to enter a double: ");
    the_double = read_double();
    printf("read_double succeeded.  It read a value of %g.\n", the_double);
    return 0;
}
```

If you need to use `fgetc()` to read the input stream, here are modified versions of `read_int` and `read_double` to convert these bytes to actual numbers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int read_int(void) {
    int c;
    int sign = 1;
    int f = 0;

    /* skip leading white space */
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) == ' ' || c == '\n')
        continue;

    /* handle optional sign */
    if (c == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        c = fgetc(stdin);
    } else
    if (c == '+') {
        c = fgetc(stdin);
    }

    /* convert digits */
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        f = c - '0';
        while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) >= '0' && c <= '9')
            f = f * 10 + c - '0';
        if (c != EOF)
            ungetc(c, stdin);
    } else {
        /* no digits: fatal error */
        if (c == EOF)
            printf("Unexpected end of file\n");
        else
            printf("Sorry that input is invalid: %c\n", c);
        exit(1);
    }
    /* apply sign and return value */
    return sign * f;
}

double read_double(void) {
    char buf[80];
    int c;
    size_t pos = 0;
    double d;
    char *p;

    /* read a line of input */
    while (pos < sizeof(buf) - 1 && (c = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF && c != '\n')
        buf[pos++] = c;
    buf[pos] = '\0';

    /* use standard library function to convert the number */
    p = buf;
    d = strtod(buf, &p);

    /* if conversion failed, report fatal error */
    if (p == buf) {
        printf("Sorry this input is invalid: %s\n", buf);
        exit(1);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: okay first of, I need to use fgetc(stdin) in this exercise so i cannot really use scanf on this one.Second, the goal is not to print integer but to produce error messages if I input some thing like this,

23.44
23abc
23.
23+44

Comment: @Elo: OK. thanks for clarifying your goal. You should read bytes from `stdin` and convert them into an integer as long as you get digits. It is relatively easy for `read_int()` but amazingly difficult to do a perfect job for `read_double()` in the general case.

Comment: @chqrlie can you give me an example? I am a complete beginner in C. I mean on converting the digits on stdin to integer.

Comment: @Elo:  I updated the answer with simple yet effective conversion code.